# How to call a function on button click that have the same variable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In HTML I created 4 buttons. One to make the video speed slower (x0.5), another one to make it at its normal speed (x1.0), another one to make its speed faster (x2.0), and the last one to make its speed very fast (x8.0). I made the buttons correctly and everything worked as how it should work, but the problem is when I try to apply these buttons to another video the buttons will work only on the second video without doing anything to the first video. And when I delete the second video, the buttons will back to work normally on the first video. I checked the console and I found no errors.

My HTML code

```html
                <h3>First video</h3>
                <video id="vfirst" controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" height="339" width="600"></video>
                <p>Video speed</p>
                <div class="sps">
                    <button class="bs" onclick="Bs()" type="button">×0.5</button>
                    <button class="bn" onclick="Bn()" type="button">×1.0</button>
                    <button class="bf" onclick="Bf()" type="button">×2.0</button>
                    <button class="bvf" onclick="Bvf()" type="button">×8.0</button>
                </div>
                <h3>Second video</h3>
                <video id="vsec" controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" height="339" width="600"></video>
                <p>Video speed</p>
                <div class="sps">
                    <button class="bs" onclick="Bs2()" type="button">×0.5</button>
                    <button class="bn" onclick="Bn2()" type="button">×1.0</button>
                    <button class="bf" onclick="Bf2()" type="button">×2.0</button>
                    <button class="bvf" onclick="Bvf2()" type="button">×8.0</button>
                </div>
                
                            <script>
                var vid = document.getElementById("vfirst");
                    function Bs() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 0.5;
                    }
                    function Bn() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 1;
                    }
                    function Bf() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 2;
                    }
                    function Bvf() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 8;
                    }
                var vid = document.getElementById("vsec");
                    function Bs2() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 0.5;
                    }
                    function Bn2() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 1;
                    }
                    function Bf2() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 2;
                    }
                    function Bvf2() {
                        vid.playbackRate = 8;
                    }
            </script>
```

Here is the same code, but the second video is deleted. Look how it works very fine.

```html
                    <h3>First video</h3>
                    <video id="vfirst" controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" height="339" width="600"></video>
                    <p>Video speed</p>
                    <div class="sps">
                        <button class="bs" onclick="Bs()" type="button">×0.5</button>
                        <button class="bn" onclick="Bn()" type="button">×1.0</button>
                        <button class="bf" onclick="Bf()" type="button">×2.0</button>
                        <button class="bvf" onclick="Bvf()" type="button">×8.0</button>
                    </div>
                    
                                <script>
                    var vid = document.getElementById("vfirst");
                        function Bs() {
                            vid.playbackRate = 0.5;
                        }
                        function Bn() {
                            vid.playbackRate = 1;
                        }
                        function Bf() {
                            vid.playbackRate = 2;
                        }
                        function Bvf() {
                            vid.playbackRate = 8;
                        }
                </script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's because you've declared `vid` twice. Give the second instance a different name. I'd also suggest you research the DRY principle to discover ways to prevent the duplication in your code.

Comment: You mean I should name it `vid2` to make it work?

Comment: Sure, that's one way to solve it.

Comment: I tried to do it, but now the problem is in reverse (the first video buttons works fine, but the second video buttons don't do anything)

Comment: Well you need to change `vid` to `vid2` in the event handlers as well..

Comment: Event handlers? Where I can find them? (I am new to `JavaScript`)

Comment: I mean your `Bs()`, `Bn()` etc. functions

Comment: I did this: `Bs(vid1)`, `Bs2(vid2)`. Now both of them are not working.

Comment: I've added an answer for you to show you a method of achieving what you need in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the variable name vid to **vid1** for the first video and **vid2** for the second video. use the below code in  tag.

```
var vid1 = document.getElementById("vfirst");
function Bs() {
    vid1.playbackRate = 0.5;
}
function Bn() {
    vid1.playbackRate = 1;
}
function Bf() {
    vid1.playbackRate = 2;
}
function Bvf() {
    vid1.playbackRate = 8;
}
var vid2 = document.getElementById("vsec");
function Bs2() {
    vid2.playbackRate = 0.5;
}
function Bn2() {
    vid2.playbackRate = 1;
}
function Bf2() {
    vid2.playbackRate = 2;
}
function Bvf2() {
    vid2.playbackRate = 8;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue in your logic is because you've redeclared `vid` so that it holds the second video when the buttons are clicked.

To fix this, and [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) the code up, you can contain the `button` and `video` elements in a single container with a class. Then when any button is clicked you can traverse the DOM to find the related video and update the speed of that instance only.

In addition, you can use `data` attributes on the button to avoid repetition within the JS, so that a single event handler will work for every button.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('.speed').on('click', e => $(e.target).closest('.video-container').find('video').prop('playbackRate', e.target.dataset.speed));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-container">
  <h3>First video</h3>
  <video id="vfirst" controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" height="150"></video>
  <p>Video speed</p>
  <div class="sps">
    <button class="speed" data-speed="0.5" type="button">×0.5</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="1" type="button">×1.0</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="2" type="button">×2.0</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="8" type="button">×8.0</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="video-container">
  <h3>Second video</h3>
  <video id="vsec" controls src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" height="150"></video>
  <p>Video speed</p>
  <div class="sps">
    <button class="speed" data-speed="0.5" type="button">×0.5</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="1" type="button">×1.0</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="2" type="button">×2.0</button>
    <button class="speed" data-speed="8" type="button">×8.0</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your reply, it worked just fine. But I actually hate to deal with jQuery (it's just too complicated), so I used the solution of the comment above of @Ayaz and it also worked.

Comment: In which case I'd strongly suggest you only include tags of technologies you want to use in your future questions. Although I don't see your point about it being too complicated when this is literally 1 line of code to work for any video you add to the DOM. The other example will need to be copied, pasted and then updated for every video.

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring `var vid` twice. either change the code to below

```
var vid1 = document.getElementById("vfirst");

var vid2 = document.getElementById("vsec");
```

or use jquery

```
$("#vfirst, #vsec").({
.. your code
});
```

that should work fine

Comment: That jQuery is invalid and will throw error

Comment: Yes, you are correct. but it should be that way. i

Comment: I tried the first one and set it to `vid1` and set it to `vid2` the only things I get is: `Uncaught ReferenceError: vid is not defined` and now the buttons don't work.

Comment: This answer misses the important point of how to address *only* the video related to each button instance.

Comment: *"It should be that way"* ... No. Not if it is completely wrong